# How to move an address to a new wallet?

Tags: wallet, address, wallet.dat

I have a wallet with several addresses. I would like to isolate one of the addresses in its own wallet, but I don't know how to do it. I've been trying with pywallet.py, but I've been unable to do it.

Can you help me, please?

**EDIT:** I've made some progress:

- I dumped my wallet with `pywallet.py --dumpwallet >wallet.json`, and searched for the key I wanted to isolate, and wrote down the field named `sec`.
- Then moved `wallet.dat` to another folder, and started bitcoin-qt, so it generated a new wallet.
- Opened `Help -> Debug window -> console` and run `importprivkey  XXXXXXXX mykeylabel`. It took about 4 minutes to import the key.

Now I still need to:

- remove this address from the old wallet.
- remove the default address in the new wallet, so it contains just the imported address.

Comment: Which client are you using?

Comment: Bitcoin-qt but I'm thinking about trying Armory

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do this? In most cases, the easiest and safest thing to do is just send bitcoins from one wallet to another.

Comment: While this is true, he might need to preserve that key if he publicized widely that address.

Comment: Right. I don't want to loose that address. I also don't want to mix balances with other addresses. Bitcoin-qt creates hidden change addresses with almost every transaction, so after a while, I can't be sure of the exact balance of an address (account?). I prefer to isolate this address and all its future related change addreses in its own wallet.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that via the [default bitcoind API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).

I suppose you are used to use Bitcoin-Qt? Then most probably the [bitcoind daemon](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) is also installed on your computer.

You can move an address from one wallet to another using the `setaccount` command. It works as follows.

`setaccount <bitcoinaddress> <account>`

So, when you have an address, let's say `1HDPmDGcgXkRTBbACYXNQ1SNeoCQEPvN3v`, that you want to move from `wallet1` to `wallet2`, then you can do the following command.

`setaccount 1HDPmDGcgXkRTBbACYXNQ1SNeoCQEPvN3v wallet2`

You can perform these commands most easily from a command line interface. In Unix systems where [bitcoind](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) is installed, you can do the following:

- Make sure Bitcoin-Qt is closed.
- Launch bitcoind as a daemon:

`bitcoind -daemon`

- Do the command I mentioned above: (It's possible that you get an error that the Bitcoin server is not yet running, just wait a little.)

`bitcoind setaccount 1HDPmDGcgXkRTBbACYXNQ1SNeoCQEPvN3v wallet2`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out `bitcoind`, I find it very interesting. I tried `setaccount` but it doesn't  generate a new wallet (wallet.dat file I can move to another computer), just a new "account" which is of no real use to me. In fact, the account which holds address I want to move to a new wallet, show a balance of several bitcoins when it should be zero, and another unnamed ("") account shows a negative balance, so it seems you can't use "accounts" to know neat balance of an address.

Comment: @FranciscoR https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained#Accounts_and_Receiving_Addresses will explain the "" unnamed account and negative balance.

Comment: An account in bitcoin is not a wallet. As explained here (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained), account is a way to categories the different addresses into groups within a wallet. Having said that, the `setaccount` method is not to transfer an address from wallet to another.

Answer (score 3):

Open Bitcoin-Qt with old wallet (Menu: Help / Debug window / Console):

```
walletpassphrase "OLDWALLETPASSPHRASE" 600
dumpprivkey "BITCOINADDRESS"
walletlock
```

...write down private key and close program. Next open Bitcoin-Qt with new wallet and import private key:

```
walletpassphrase "NEWWALLETPASSPHRASE" 600
importprivkey "BITCOINPRIVKEYFROMOLDWALLET" "SOMELABEL"
walletlock
```

...wait for rescan and lock wallet. That is all without other programs etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin-Qt client currently does not provide any method to delete addresses.  You can create a new wallet and import a subset of the private keys from the old wallet to create a wallet that doesn't have certain private keys/addresses.

Comment: Do you know how can I create a new empty wallet, with 0 addresses in it? I tried renaming wallet.dat, and Bitcoin-qt creates a new wallet, but there is always an address in it.

Answer (score 0):

The Bitcoin-Qt client currently does not provide any method to delete addresses. You can create a new wallet and import a subset of the private keys from the old wallet to create a wallet that doesn't have certain private keys/addresses.